# Example of pseudo-peripheral vertex which is not peripheral vertex

Tags: graphs

I need to find an example of a [pseudo-peripheral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_(graph_theory)) vertex which is not a peripheral vertex. I came up with this example, where diameter is 4 and pseudo-peripheral vertices labeled aqua. Am i right here?

$$\mbox{dia} = 4$$
$$e(9) = e(4) < \mbox{dia}, e(8) = e(4) < \mbox{dia}$$

[image]

Could you provide other examples? Maybe some interesting theorem on how to build such?

Comment: What is a peripheral vertex? What is a pseudo-peripheral vertex?

Comment: Also, it seems like you already have a solution.

Comment: We want questions here to be self-contained, so it would help to include the definition of peripheral and pseudo-peripheral in the question itself.  Also, we discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. The site works better if you can ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about. As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on.